# Open Google Traffic within openlayers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

I am using openlayers to get google map in my web application which works fine.

I now want to get google live Traffic but how do I do this with openlayers? (I have a APPID etc from google account)

My openlayers code is

```
var gmapLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("GMaps");
map.addLayers([gmapLayer]);
```

but to get google traffic feed I have to write the code below in which case I loose openlayers

```
 var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
 var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
 trafficLayer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the 'map' variable the moment you initialize google maps directly and sort of bypassing the openlayers code.  The map you instantiated with openlayers is now a google map one.  The trick is to add traffic as an overlay.  There is little to find online on that subject.